# Recursive routine in C to print a string in reverse

Tags: c, string, recursion

In the below sample program, Can anyone please help in the difference between the output of 2 functions?

As per my understanding output of both the function should be same.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printRevStr1(char *ptr)
{
        if(*ptr)
        {
                printRevStr1(ptr+1);
                printf("%c",*ptr);
        }
}
void printRevStr2(char *ptr)
{
        if(*ptr)
        {
                ptr++;
                printRevStr2(ptr);
                printf("%c",*ptr);
        }
}
main()
{
        char arr[100]="Stackoverflow";
        printRevStr1(arr);
        printf("\n");
        printRevStr2(arr);
        printf("\n");
}
```

Below is the output,

**Output**

```
wolfrevokcatS
wolfrevokcat
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger?

Comment: What is the value of `ptr` at `printf("%c",*ptr);` in both the function at the very first instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is very simple.

Just check the following explanation function-wise:

```
void printRevStr1(char *ptr)
{
        if(*ptr)
        {
                printRevStr1(ptr+1);
                printf("%c",*ptr);
        }
}
```

While you implement this function, what you get as input the the string `Stackoverflow`
Then you just reverse the string and print it.

While in the second function:

```
void printRevStr2(char *ptr)
{
        if(*ptr)
        {
                ptr++;
                printRevStr2(ptr);
                printf("%c",*ptr);
        }
}
```

The statement you have writted before printing:  `ptr++;` is shift the pointer to next character in your string. That is you now the string becomes `tackoverflow`

And hence you received such output. I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine... but you're advancing and printing the next character, when really it's the previous one you should be printing:

```
void printRevStr2(char *ptr)
{
    if(*ptr)
    {
        ptr++;                   
        printRevStr2(ptr);
        printf("%c",*(ptr - 1)); // <----- here

    }
}
```

This gives

```
wolfrevokcatS
wolfrevokcatS
```